# Can one malloc call be used to allocate two arrays?

Tags: c, malloc

If I know, that too types T and U have same alignment, can I use one malloc call like this:

```
void* allocate_memory(int n, int m) {
  return malloc(sizeof(T) * n + sizeof(U) * m);
}
```

to allocate contiguous memory for arrays of these two types?

If it is okay, what is the correct way to acquire the pointer to the first element of the second array? Conversion void* -> char* -> (+= sizeof(T) * n) -> U* seems fine, but I feel like there might be some kind of undefined behaviour there.

(I'm almost sure it can't be done in C++, rules of pointer arithmetic won't allow this (At no point array of U starts to exist, so you can't perform pointer arithmetic on this storage). Hence my cautiousness about C rules)

edit:

Since [P0593R6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html) got accepted and applied as Defect Report to all C++ standards back to C++98, a call to malloc implicitly creates objects in allocated storage. Because of that, this construction is now valid in C++ too and pointer arithmetic on this range is well-defined as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, you can perform arithmetic on the full allocated object via its *representation array*, which has type `unsigned char []` but can legally be addressed (less verbosely) via just `char *`. I'm not sure about in C++ but I would think you could do the same.

If `p` is the pointer returned, `(U *)((char *)p + sizeof(T) * n)` is a valid pointer to what you want.

Note that you can get rid of the "same alignment" requirement just by using `_Alignof(U)` or by using `sizeof(U)` (or the highest power of two that divides it) as a (not necessarily sharp) estimate for the alignment and working out the necessary padding in between to reach a multiple of the alignment. If you do this make sure to allocate the right total amount including the padding.